# opening an excel from a .hlp file

Tags: vb.net, helpfile

I am using the Microsoft Help workshop that compiles a .rtf file and generates a .hlp file which I attach to my vb application.
The thing is I want a link on the help file which when clicked opens an Excel. I am NOT using the HTML help version.(I have to use the Microsoft help workshop only)

Answer (score 0):

While chm has the ability to launch external programs (examples [here](http://kb.helpwaregroup.com/ms-html-help/hh-tips-tricks#Applets)), it may be restricted by [group policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms524374%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Check with your admin for details on their restrictions